# Getting shutdown error in RabbitMQ consumers

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a cluster of rabbitmq nodes and few days back I pulled one node due to some maintainance activity and pushed it back in the quorum after the activity was done.
After this activity few consumers are getting shut down error like this: "Thread: amq.ctag-UxwY2w2_qqT4mUg2QUO18g shutdown"
After this the nodes marks a consumer as not available and messages stays at ready state.
Is there any thing that I did wrong while pulling the node, please help.

Comment: What version are you using? Also show more details (logs).

Comment: I am using v3.6.1  version of rabbit

Comment: I meant what version of spring-amqp (and you still need to show more information).